# Why does package routine's @_ contain Package name, whether params passed or not?

Tags: perl

My basic question is this. If I pass no parameters to my package -- `DbIoFunc`'s routine `OpenIcsDB()` why is the pacakge name in `@_`?

I am expecting @_ to be null when I pass no parameters to the following function, but instead the parameter contains the package name. I have tried calling with class `->` and `::` syntax, and there is no difference.

What should I test to determine if no parameter was passed other than the following?

```
my ($Temp, $DBPathLocal) = @_; 

if(!defined $DBPathLocal)
{
    $DBPathLocal = DBDEV;
}
```

I'm wondering two things. Why is the package name part of `@_` and is what I've done the best way to get rid of the package name?

Here is the call:

```
my ($DBHand);
$DBHand = DbIoFunc->OpenIcsDb();
```

Here is the function:

```
sub OpenIcsDb
#
# DB Path Constant DBPROD or DBDEV.
#
{
    # Path passed in, either DBPROD or DBDEV
    my ($DBPathLocal); 

    my ($DBSuffix);
    my ($DBHand);      # ICS database handle

    $DBPathLocal = shift;

    #
    # Make sure the database path exists.
    #

    if (length($DBPathLocal) <= 0)
    {
        if (!$Debugging)
        {
            $DBPathLocal= DBPROD;
        }
        else
        {
            $DBPathLocal = DBDEV;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $DBPathLocal = DBDEV;
    }

    my $DBSuffix = DBSUFFIX;

    $! = 2;
    die("Can't find database directory ".$DBPathLocal.".".$DBSuffix)
    unless ((-e $DBPathLocal.".".$DBSuffix) && (-d $DBPathLocal.".".$DBSuffix));
    #
    # See if we can connect to the ICS database.  We can't proceed without it.
    #
    $DBHand = DBI->connect("dbi:Informix:".$DBPathLocal, "", "")
        or die("Can't connect to the ICS database ".$DBPathLocal);

    return $DBHand;
}
```

Comment: `if (defined $yourVar)`

Comment: Why transform conditionals into unreadable constructs? The nested if block could've been trivially written as a single conditional.

Comment: @stackErr If I shift @_ into $DBHand, I get the package name, so the parameter is not undef. I am not seeing how to determine if the parameter is not present.

Comment: Is it quite intentional that `length($DBPathLocal)` is checked to be possibly less than zero?

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect `length(@_)` to do, but it'll never be 0.

Comment: This question is not quite an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8299662/9719 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do OOP, Perl has to know the package name or the object's reference to work. If you use the `::` call method, you avoid this.

```
package Foo;

sub bar {
  print "@_\n";
}

package main;

Foo->bar();
Foo::bar();
bar Foo();
```

Note that the call to `Foo::bar();` does not print the package name.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check this out after the holiday weekend. I'll go see if the package name prints. I'm inclined to use class syntax, given that's used all over our Perl code -- there is quite a bit of it -- and I like continuity. I've gone for a package name throw away concept that I put in the edited OP.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to call the function as `DbIoFunc::OpenIcsDb()`. Using the arrow operator does some object stuff.

Comment: Or if it's supposed to be a "class method", skip or verify the classname argument.

Comment: It's a method in a package.

Comment: @aschepler I know this is perl and TIMTOWTDI, but I would assume that if he meant to be calling class methods there would be a "new" in here somewhere.

Comment: @AKHolland In perl, "new" is only useful for calling a method which is actually named "new".

Comment: @aschepler I'm aware of that, hence the disclaimer at the beginning of my previous comment. However, **in general**, if someone meant to be using object methods they would create an object with `new` first.

Comment: I unaccepted this, because $DBPathLocal still contains DbIoFunc, and I've deleted my answer, because it was incorrect, too.

Comment: @AKHolland: but it was being called as a class method, not an object method.

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried calling with class -> and :: syntax, and there is no difference.

There is a difference. If you use `::` and pass no other parameters then `@_` **will** be empty. You can confirm this fact by inserting the following code at the top of the function:

```
print '@_ contains ' . scalar(@_) . " elements\n";
```

Your real problem might be here:

```
$DBPathLocal = shift;
if (length($DBPathLocal) <= 0)
```

If `@_` is empty then `$DBPathLocal` will be `undef`. And `length(undef)` is always `undef`. And `undef <= 0` is always **true**.

Protip:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
```

Comment: Sorry. @_ was not empty, when I passed no parameters. This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for i386-linux-thread-multi

Comment: @octopusgrabbus I edited my answer. Try inserting the `print` line I added and see what it says.

Comment: What I've decided to do is throw away the Package name in a scalar variable. Most of our Perl code uses `->` syntax, and I want to keep using it for continuity.